# unable to download the file using HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#

I am unable to download the file because of finally block. When I comment the code in finally block, I am able to download the file. When I try to close the fileStream object in finally block I am unable to download the file and when I comment out the code in finally block, I am able to download the file. Not sure what causing the issue. How to achieve this by using finally block.

```
        if (File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open);
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            try
            {
                response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = fileName };
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
            finally
            {
                if (fileStream != null)
                    fileStream.Close();
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Jquery code will be like

```
  function openFile() {
    var fileName = $(this).closest(".file-box").find(".file-name").text();
    var encodedFileName = encodeURIComponent(fileName);
    $(document.body).showLoaderWithText("Downloading File");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/ProcurementApi/Open?savInitId=" + mv.options.savInitId + "&fileName=" + encodedFileName,
        
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: "blob"
        },
        global: false,
        success: function (blob) {
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
            } else {
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = fileName;
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                $(document.body).resetLoader();

            }
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
            if (/^not found$/ig.test(thrownError)) {
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            $(document.body).resetLoader();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `HttpResponseMessage` is for an `HttpClient`, not for returning a result for an api

Comment: I am able to download the file if comment out  ""if (fileStream != null) fileStream.Close(); "" If I uncomment that one I am not able to download it. Why is that and how can i fix it?